# Не получается создать базу данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Добрый день.

Проблема описана ниже.
 Выдержка из учебника:
 "... база данных добавляется в проект, и мы можем увидеть ее в папке App_Data. Теперь в обозревателе баз данных (окно Database Explorer) мы можем подключиться к ней и создать таблицы, которые будут хранить данные.
 Раскроем узел Creditbook.mdf и найдем узел Tables. Нажмем на этот узел правой кнопкой мыши и в появившемся меню выберем пункт Add New Table."

У меня нет пункта Add New Table, есть только Обновить и Свойства. (У меня стоят SQL Server и Management Studio). 
 Вот тут (http://www.sql.ru/forum/1038127/redaktirovanie-bd-v-s), у человека была такая же проблема, но я всё равно не понял, что нужно делать. 
 Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если ты используешь Entity Framework, то у меня аналогичная проблема- база данных не создается в sql server, а в папках проекта ее тоже нет.

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать скриншот/версию VS/connectionString из web.config (если там не содержится пароль, конечно)?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно установить [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)
Проверял на Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Либо зайдите под админом в студию, либо поставьте себе SqlManagementStudio.

Comment: SQL Management Studio установлена. А как зайти в студию под администратором?(правый клик по exe'шнику, run as admin - так не работает всё равно)

Comment: Хм, интересно.
Тогда заходите в SqlManagementStudio и в ней создавайте БД.

Answer (score 0):

Базу после создания таблицы нужно обновить, тогда вновь созданная таблица станет доступна  (кнопка обновления прямо над ID).Обозреватель баз данных после данных действий также обновить желательно (кнопка левый верхний угол). В остальном все правильно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня решение было таким: в VS жмем Tools->Extensions and Updates, выбрал обновление для VS, дальше надо поставить галочки, подождать пока установится и все заработает. По крайней мере у меня заработало.